# Send dispatch and redirect after state is updated in redux ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, dispatch

I am new in front end development. Now I do study project (simple task editor, without server side) on base of reactJs+redux. I encounter with next problem.

I have some component that show web page on url '/addTask/'.

```
const TaskCreator = ({ tasks, onAddTask }) => {

 ...

 const addTask = () => { 

 const newTask = {
   id: newId,
   header: headerInput.value,
   description: descriptionInput.value
 }

 onAddTask(newTask);
}

return(
 <div>

     ...

    <button className='btn btn-success' onClick={addTask}>Save</button>

</div>
 );
}

export default connect(
(state) => ({
tasks: state.tasks
}),
dispatch => ({

onAddTask: (task) => {
  const payload = {
    id: task.id,
    header: task.header,
    description: task.description
  };
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TASK', payload });
  browserHistory.push('/');
}


})
)(TaskCreator);
```

When user click on button `Save`. `addTask` has called. After that `onAddTask` method faired and `ADD_TASK` task command disptached. 
After new task has added to state there is need to redirect to url `/`.

When I insert statement `browserHistory.push('/')`, browser redirect to url `/` but it didn't update state with new task. If I delete statement `browserHistory.push('/')` like that

```
onAddTask: (task) => {
  const payload = {
    id: task.id,
    header: task.header,
    description: task.description
  };
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TASK', payload });

}
```

The state updated but browser didn't redirect.

How can I asynchronously update state (using dispatch) and after state has updated, redirect to url `/` ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Have you tried to use .then after dispatching an action to do the redirects AFTER your dispatch succesfully fired?

Comment: @AndyTheos, I tried to use `dispatch(addTaskAction(task)).then((response) => {
            dispatch(push('/'));
        });` But I got error: **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

You should to know how treat async (like chain reaction) in react and redux.

Redux-saga helps you. https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: Thank you for helping. I found that my problem was in clearing state of redux after reloading browser page and that why `push('/')` didn't work. When I manuall type '/' **state** not clear. I need a programmatical command that work exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found workaround of my problem.

Really, my problem was in clearing `state` during browser reload. And when I try to use `push(`/`)` it reload webpage so `state` variable cleared and  can't see new (added in '/addTask/' page) tasks on '/' url.

To avoid clearing webpage there is need to go back (in browser) or manually print '/' url. I found programmatical analog for manual enter '/' url. To do this there is need to change:

```
 <button className='btn btn-success' onClick={addTask}>Save</button>
```

to Link with `to` attribute that manual redirect:

```
<Link className='btn btn-success' to=`/` onClick={addTask}>Сохранить</Link>
```

`onClick` handle click (save new task) and `to` redirect to '/' url.

Thank you all for answers.